# DefineDosDevice GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint

Tags: winapi, volume

MSDN has a nice example of changing drive letters at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364014(v=vs.85).aspx

Only problem is that it doesn't work on my Windows 7 system.
Am invoking the EXE from a DOS window with admin privileges.
I start with a thumb drive on E:
I can use the MSDN example to remove E:
But when I then use the MSDN example to assign F: to the same thumb drive, the initial DefineDosDevice for F: succeeds, but the subsequent GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint fails thus SetVolumeMountPoint fails.
I understand that the function of the initial DefineDosDevice is to create the drive letter so there's something for GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint to connect to and thus return the volume name, but GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint is behaving as if the intial DefineDosDevice has failed.
Whassup?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the second argument to ChangeLetter.exe when defining a new drive. You must include the partition number. Assume USB drive is set for E: and you want to move it to F:. You must do the following:

ChangeLetter -r E:
ChangeLetter F: \device\harddisk1\partition1

Harddisk counts from zero. Partition counts from one.